# Problem with the \mathbf command

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode, formatting, bold

In this MWE, I want to obtain bold letter for the letter "H" (compare the two "H") :

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{lmodern} % load a font with all the characters
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
\usepackage{amsmath}%loads amsmath that should go before unicode-math
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}  % This seems to be important for mapping glyphs properly

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\mbox{First bold H : }\|x\|_{\mathbf{H}},\; \mbox{Second bold H : }\mathbf{H} 
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but I don't know how doing it.
THe "H" produced by this MWE is tiny but no bold effect. If I use

> \SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

I obtain bold tiny "H" but the font used still not the same.

Comment: Just how is this minimal? It is far from that.

Comment: question edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For sizes below 10pt the cmbright package is subsetting bold fonts (which don't exists) and uses the normal weight instead. You can change this by adding this code behind cmbright:

```
\usepackage{cmbright}
\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmbr}\selectfont %to load ot1cmbr.fd
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}{% change bx definition
<->cmbrbx10%
}{}
\normalfont % back to normalfont
```

Comment: While this works for me too it appears that it also changes the beamer footer to normal weight (which was bold weight beforehand).

Answer (score 8):

You can simply load `unicode-math`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{lmodern} % load a font with all the characters
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}%loads amsmath that should go before unicode-math
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}  % This seems to be important for mapping glyphs properly

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\|x\|_{\mathbf{H}}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}%loads amsmath that should go before unicode-math` ... and then you load it after. `:)`

Comment: The math font I used is loaded by the cmbright package. I want to keep this font and obtain a bold letter "H" in math mode when writing for example $x_{\mathbf{H}}$ (I edited my MWE to see the difference between two bold "H").

Comment: It's a pity I couldn't use this package with pdflatex. ``unicode-math Error: Cannot be run with pdftex``

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. `unicode-math` proposed by @karlkoeller didn't work for me, because I use `pdflatex`.

I had a word with a superscript. I managed to make them both bold with `mbox` and usual text `bfseries` (needed to write that two times).

```
$\mbox{\bfseries Ge}^{\mbox{\bfseries 76}}$
```